# How to run URL after reboot system in Firefox via cron job

Tags: cron, reboot

@reboot export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox start_http://127.0.0.1:1340/#/login?redirect=%2Fdashboard

this one is not working

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run any GUI application at reboot, because at the moment the system reboots there's no GUI yet.

First you have to introduce some delay after reboot. Second, you need to ensure that your cron job has the XAUTHORITY environment variable set to the same value as in the user session that is currrently logged on display :0. (This also means that the job will fail if there is no user logged in on display :0 yet).

A better solution is to run your script at GNOME session startup, not at reboot. Just add the script to "Startup programs" in GNOME using appropriate GUI option.